# Bitwise XOR on unsigned char is terminating program without error

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to create a 64 bit integer as class in C++, I know this already exists in the C header stdint.h but I thought it could be a fun challenge.

Anyway, I am trying to perform a bitwise XOR operation on three unsigned chars, and the program keeps stopping without warning, it just pauses for a split second and then stops:

```cpp
unsigned char* a = (unsigned char*) 1;
unsigned char* b = (unsigned char*) 2;
unsigned char* c = (unsigned char*) 3;

unsigned char* result = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));

std::cout << "Trying" << std::endl;
*result = *a ^ *b ^ *c;
std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
```

The output being:

```
PS C:\Users\super\Desktop> ./test.exe
Trying
PS C:\Users\super\Desktop>
```

I am using Windows 10 if that helps, let me know if you need any other information, and thanks for any help you can give me :)

Comment: Run a debug build in the IDE and you'll probably see an access violation from attempting to read memory at addresses 1, 2, 3.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `unsigned char* a = (unsigned char*) 1;`, exactly what do you expect that to mean? Also in your own words: what is the purpose of using pointers, in general? What is the purpose of using `malloc`?

Comment: The part of my code that this is from requires these values to be pointers, which is also the same reason I use malloc here, for this specific example it is not necessary I know, but for the part of my code that I took this from it was needed. I thought ```unsigned char* a = (unsigned char*) 1```  would mean that ```a``` would be assigned to a pointer to an ```unsigned char``` object containing the value 1, clearly I was wrong. I am relatively new to C++, so clearly I need to do more research on the proper use of pointers.

Comment: `a`, `b`, and `c` are pointers with manually assigned values - and the addresses may not exist as far as your program is concerned.   Dereferencing any of them (accessing whatever they point at) therefore gives undefined behaviour.   The statement `*result = *a ^ *b ^ *c` dereferences ALL of them, so definitely gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to dereference invalid pointers. You want to get rid of a lot of those `*`s.

```
unsigned char a = 1;
unsigned char b = 2;
unsigned char c = 3;

unsigned char* result = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));

std::cout << "Trying" << std::endl;
*result = a ^ b ^ c;
std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
```

Why are you allocating a single byte (`sizeof(unsigned char)` is `1` by definition) on the heap for the result? You could just make that another `unsigned char` variable, too.

Editorial note: you also [don't need to use `std::endl`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avoid-using-stdendl/).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it did work, out of interest what exactly makes them invalid pointers?

Comment: The bit where you assign them integer address values which are very obviously not the addresses of real objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is crashing because you are dereferencing pointers `a`,`b`,`c` which are not pointing at valid memory addresses that can be read from.

[Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72333469/65863) shows you how to rewrite this code to not use pointers at all for `a`,`b`,`c`.

But, if for some reason, you actually did need to pass around integers type-casted as pointers (for instance, because you are passing them through a C API that requires this), then you need to **type-cast** the pointers back into integers, not **dereference** the pointers, eg:

```
unsigned char* a = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(1));
unsigned char* b = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(2));
unsigned char* c = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(3));

unsigned char* result = new unsigned char;

std::cout << "Trying" << std::endl;
*result = static_cast<unsigned char>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(a))
        ^ static_cast<unsigned char>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(b))
        ^ static_cast<unsigned char>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(c));
std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;

...

delete result;
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I see now, I was thinking about 1 2 and 3 like integers objects, not as binary that would be interpreted as a memory address.